# C# - Selected item in list box unselects itself when I press a button

Tags: c#

Upon pressing my button that pulls the text from my listbox selected item, the selected item no long is selected, and when the text is sent to a "console" textbox the text that would be there, is not there because before it actually makes it to the textbox, it becomes unselected.

```
private void SpellsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populateSpells();
    if (SpellsButton.Text == "Cast")
    {
        string spell = Backpack_Spells.GetItemText(Backpack_Spells.SelectedItem);
        attemptCast(spell);
    }
    SpellsButton.Text = "Cast";
    RunButton.Text = "Cancel";
}

private void attemptCast(string spell)
{
    consoleOutput.AppendText( "Casting " + spell + "\r\n");
}//by the time it makes it here, the selection is no longer selected so the program is unable to find the selections text

private void Backpack_Spells_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    consoleOutput.AppendText(Backpack_Spells.GetItemText(Backpack_Spells.SelectedItem)+ "\n");
}//When a listbox selection is clicked, this fires and outputs the spell.
```

I am unsure why the button unselects my selection. The last one, where the index change is how it's put into the textbox makes sense how it works, I just dont know why the first one doesn't. Any help  would be grateful :)

Comment: Probably a dumb question, but have you checked to see if it's doing a postback on selection?  Because that would reset the page to the original state, which would clear your selection.

Comment: No, not a dumb question, I'll be 100% honest with you. I have no idea what a post back is lol

Comment: Let me guess, `populateSpells()` fills in (aka, _resets_) the `Backpack_Spells` list?

Comment: Put a break point in your code in the Page_Load event.  When you click the button, if it stops at the break point then it's doing a postback, which means it's reloading the entire page.  The only way to avoid that is to set the AutoPostBack = "False" in your listbox.  So, like, <asp:listbox ID="Whatever" AutoPostBack="False" />.  Or, in the Page_Load event, you can have an If/Then where it checks to see if it's a postback, and if it is then it doesn't reload the list of spells.

Comment: Why don't you try stopping event propagation like this: e.Handled = true; ?

Comment: Unclear here...is this a WinForms or a WebForms application?

Comment: If what @Nyerguds says is correct, then simply move the line "string spell = Backpack_Spells.GetItemText(Backpack_Spells.SelectedItem);" to before populateSpells.

Comment: What was there in `populateSpells` I guess you are setting default values. If it is a web application **(Asp.net)** call that inside `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: Is `HideSelection` on or off?

Comment: The populateSpells() just adds items to the listbox while im testing... Oh... I see what's happening Nyerguds. Lemme see if I can fix that... lol.... Facepalm. That fixed it... I swear I'm dumb sometimes, please dont judge

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks to Nyerguds, for pointing out an oversight.
Let me guess, populateSpells() fills in (aka, resets) the Backpack_Spells list? – Nyerguds

He was correct. I didn't even think of it overwriting the textbox while I was pressed the button multiple times. added one line and it fixed the problem....

```
if (SpellsButton.Text == "Spells")
populateSpells();//Fills in the spells index
```